# Furry mint taking over my yard?

Tags: herbs

Probably 8 ish years ago my husband planted an herb garden but over the years it has become overgrown. This spring though, a plant that smells exactly like mint and after tasting a small amount of one of the leaves, it tastes like mint too. The thing is though, it doesn't look like mint. The way the plant grows is similar but the leaves are furry is and more rounded, and the plant has a square stem. We've tried researching it but none of the varieties of mint fit the description. Does anyone know what this could be??

Comment: If you have a picture, that would be most helpful. square stem is a good indicator that it's some kind of mint species, but there are lots of mint species out there.

Answer (score 3):

Mint stems are normally square.

Apple mint is one example of a common "furry" leaved mint.

[image: apple mint image from laurel mountain farm website.]

Like most mints, it can be invasive.

Answer (score 3):

Another furry member of the Lamiaceae or mint family is Lamb's Ear. [See photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stachys_byzantina#/media/File:Stachys_lanata_01.jpg) It's pretty common and I could see it surviving a forgotten garden. If it is this, then keep it around for the bees and feel free to dead head after flowering.